# Selenium chrome driver throws password field not intractable error

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium chrome driver nugget package with . Net core for browser automation. I am facing an issue whenever I try to set text inside password field. I tried to implement most of the suggestions on stackoverflow and other sites but nothing seems working. I tied to use wait.until elements is visible and wait.until elements is clickable and tried sleeping the current thread for considerable time but none of the solution is working.

I am not getting this error while debugging it. Please help if you have solution around it.

Comment: Can you share page URL ?

Comment: Hi Cruisepandey, the url as it is internal to my organization and not accessible publicly.

Comment: okay I understand that, can you show us page resource in that case?

Comment: @AlokBakshith Welcome to SO! Please read [tour] and [mcve] and edit your post in order to receive proper answer.